# When QTP is installed with Java Addin, an client application developed in Java does not launch

Tags: java, qtp

Problem: An application developed in Java does not launch when used with QTP having Java Addin enabled

When Java Addin is enable in QTP, the following environment variables is set

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS : -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar

IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS : -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
```

When we try to launch the Java Client application for which we need to automate, it fails to launch

We tried removing the above environment variables but the QTP fails to recognize the objects in the Java Client application

Comment: Could you provide some error log ?

Comment: This is what I found in the trace logs, com.bo.migration.MigrationApp||Error in reading properties file
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\MigrationSystem.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
 at com.bo.migration.MigrationApp.<clinit>(MigrationApp.java:449)
 at com.bo.migration.MigrationTool.main(MigrationTool.java:648)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issues. After much of tries, I recognize that change Environment Variable is not the perfect way to solve this.
Try somethings:

- Update Oracle java to latest (8 as now), UFT 12.02 well supports jdk 1.8.

If Oracle jdk version <> UFT jdk version:

- Open Java Control Panel > Java > View > User tab: Find & active both of them.

The last way, change System Variables:

- Having 3 variables need to edit: _JAVA_OPTIONS,JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS. Should add these values to user environment and should work on there, leave system environment as default or empty (i means "space"):

Empty all them then reinstall Oracle Java first.
Now, your java app will work well but UFT cannot recognize java applet.
Change 3 environment variables above back to QTP path (such as:

> _JAVA_TOOLS = -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\HP\Unified Functional
>   Testing\bin\java_shared\classes";"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified
>   Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"
>
> JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -agentlib:jvmhook
>   )

Restart all to get affect, QTP now work well with java.